# QNetworkReply: Network access is disabled in QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwebview, qnetworkaccessmanager

I cannot load website into my QWebView, QNetworkReply is returning me the error: **Network Access is disabled**. Loading files from local works.

I am using Qt5. Does anyone know why is connection disabled and how this line affects this situation:

> `QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(false);`

My eth0 connection works properly, and I am able to ping any website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Qt doc : `calling setUseSystemConfiguration() overrides any application proxy or proxy factory that was previously set.` So be careful to not have set any other proxy before.

Moreover, if you want to check the Network access, you might do it that way :

```
QNetworkAccessManager   m_pManager;
QNetworkConfigurationManager configManager;    
m_pManager.setConfiguration(configManager.defaultConfiguration());

connect(&m_pManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
connect(&m_pManager, SIGNAL(networkAccessibleChanged(QNetworkAccessManager::NetworkAccessibility)), this, SLOT(networkAccessibleChanged(QNetworkAccessManager::NetworkAccessibility)));
```

and in your slot :

```
if(accessible != QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible)
    {
        // case where the network is not available
    }
```

And for the reply, you can check in the slot `replyFinished()` if there was an error during the process.