# Network access is disabled error in PhantomJs

Tags: c++, qt, phantomjs, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm getting `code 99. Description: Network access is disabled.` in PhantomJs when there is a change in network. If connection turned-off and then turned-on  PhantomJs is not detecting that and continuously throwing the error. How can I fix this issue? 
Is there any config settings that I have to specify?

Is it related to [QNetworkReply: Network access is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337304/qnetworkreply-network-access-is-disabled-in-qwebview)

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Interesting problem. What if you tried to set a proxy when that happens?

Comment: I'm not aware of setting the proxy. Is there any resource available about setting proxy?

Comment: It's possible to do [from PhantomJS script](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/11829).

Comment: Can I fix the issue through setting the proxy? I feel it's something related to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36132768/3748666). I'm using Phantom Ghost driver with Java.

Comment: Don't know if it can help, but you can try.

Comment: @Vaviloff It's not helping.